# Rails checbox boolean values won't insert anything into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I've been trying to get this thing to work for a while now and there doesn't seem to be anything that makes it work, I already tried a lot of stuff from the examples available and none of them work. I'm not sure whats going on my controller has the correct strong parameters and the form has the correct attributes.

Anyway here is my code:

```
def survey_params
    params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :status, :user_id, 
        questions_attributes:[:id, :question_content, :survey_id])
end
```

The attribute in question is status, it does not seem to want to use it whenever I place it in my form. Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'question_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :status%>
    <%= f.label :status, "Publish(only check this if you are sure 
    this is your final version of the survey)"%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The relevant part is this:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :status%>
        <%= f.label :status, "Publish(only check this if you are sure 
        this is your final version of the survey)"%>
</div>
```

I also made sure that this is in the survey model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

So I don't understand why it won't work, because everything is set so that it works. I also tried using `check_box_tag(:status)` it did not work either. It is supposed to insert a 1 or a 0 into the database. Don't know if that is already supposed to happen or not with the way it is setup, I've seen some people saying they insert true or false, but then booleans in databases(to my knowledge) are simply 1s or 0s.

Comment: Boolean columns are typically allow `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`, not just simply 1s and 0s.

Comment: Ok, thats fine, and all but what I've got right now is a column of integers not booleans. Maybe if I change it this works or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just changed the status column from `t.integer` to `t.boolean`

Leaving this example of my migrate here just in case someone runs into this issue.

class CreateSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  def change
    create_table :surveys do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :status
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for the clarification Wizard of Ogz, that helped me figure it out.